# I'm having this error bad event type or key in making snake game, by using turtle graphic in PyCharm

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):


        self.adding_dots = []
        self.create_snake()
        self.head = self.adding_dots[0]


    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITION:
            segment = Turtle("square")
            segment.color("white")
            segment.penup()
            segment.goto(position)
            self.adding_dots.append(segment)

    def move(self):
        for moving in range(len(self.adding_dots) - 1, 0, - 1):
            new_x = self.adding_dots[moving - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.adding_dots[moving - 1].ycor()
            self.adding_dots[moving].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.head[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

    def up(self):
        self.head.setheading(90)

    def down(self):
        self.head.setheading(270)

    def left(self):
        self.head.setheading(180)

    def right(self):
        self.head.setheading(0)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\PycharmProjects\Day_20\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    screen.onkey(game.up, "up")
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1395, in onkey
    self._onkeyrelease(fun, key)
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in _onkeyrelease
    self.cv.bind("<KeyRelease-%s>" % key, eventfun)
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 417, in bind
    self._canvas.bind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1421, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1375, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "up"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the direction control part, you should use uppercase for the first letter.
on your main.py, line 14
It should be

```
screen.onkey(game.up, "Up")
```

The same for the other directions ->Up, Down, Left, Right